# Is there a way to make the of input channels in python equals to dimension of filters?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm

My problem here that I want to make the number of input channels in python equals to dimension of filters

i already tried to reshape but it gives me the same error .. and because I am new in python I couldn't understand how to fix my error
My model is about combining cnn with lstm layer and i have 2892 training images and 1896 testing images with total 4788 images each image with size 128*128

here some code of what i had tried

```
cnn_model = Sequential()

cnn_model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(128,128,3)))
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

cnn_model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

cnn_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

cnn_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn_model.add(Flatten())

model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn_model, input_shape=(1,128, 128,3)))
model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

X_data = np.array(X_data)
X_datatest = np.array(X_datatest)
X_data= X_data.astype('float32') / 255.
X_datatest = X_datatest.astype('float32') / 255.


hist=model.fit(X_data, X_data,epochs=15,batch_size=128,verbose = 2,validation_data=(X_datatest, X_datatest))
```

when trying the previuos code the following error showed up

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\bdyssm\Desktop\Master\LSTMCNN2.py", line 219, in 
>       hist=model.fit(X_data, X_data,epochs=15,batch_size=128,verbose = 2,validation_data=(X_datatest, X_datatest))   File
>   "C:\Users\bdyssm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 952, in fit
>       batch_size=batch_size)   File "C:\Users\bdyssm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 751, in _standardize_user_data
>       exception_prefix='input')   File "C:\Users\bdyssm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py",
>   line 128, in standardize_input_data
>       'with shape ' + str(data_shape)) ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got
>   array with shape (2892, 28, 28, 3)

This is the model summary 
[image]

This is the cnn_model summary

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `cnn_model` has changed the shape of your signal to have 128 channels insteal of 3 color channels, but you are not taking this into account when declaring the input shape of `model`.

Examine the output shape of `cnn_model` with `cnn_model.summary()` and make sure to have input shape of `model` equal to the output shape of `cnn_model`.

Comment: unfortunately this is not helping me.. because i know the problem that you mentiond but i couldn't find a solution for it or how to fix it in python code because I am new to write a python code in deep learning

Comment: I might be able to help furhter once you post the output of cnn_model.summary(). Based on this the line model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn_model, input_shape=(None,16,128, 128,3))) will change to model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn_model, input_shape=(None,X, Y,128))).

Comment: what do you mean by X and Y?

Comment: i have edited the question with the summary and changed the input_shape to be input_shape=(1,128, 128,3) .. but gets me another error

 "ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (2892, 28, 28, 3)

Comment: please add summary for cnn_model

Comment: i have added the the cnn_model summary

Comment: I also tried another solution but it gets me another error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328025/is-there-a-way-to-fix-the-dense-layer-shape-when-adding-conv2d-layer-with-lstm